# Different methods of reading a text file?

Tags: c++, filestream

What would be the best method of reading in a text file that has integer and character input to be used for different constructors.

For example, the input file I'm reading in contains:

```
10 10 

2 3

D 7 8

C 4 3

W 1 2

W 5 5
```

I have constructors set up to take the first two lines, `struct(int foo1, int foo2)`

And a different constructor to take the rest of the lines, `struct(char foo, int foo1, int foo2)`

The best way I can think to do this is to read the text file as strings, line by line, and then cast the character integer indices to actual integers...

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: But be careful when you `cast`. I'm sure what you meant to say was, then *convert* the characters to actual integers. Casting is something else.

Comment: Hi, Please provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Answer (score 0):

This file contain logs, line by line, and each line maybe one of several types. Determining the type of each line is needed before parsing it. So a general way to load the file is read each line as a string, since it's difficult to do something before knowing what type it is.